# Finding the solvable configurations, and the group of "moves", for the 8-puzzle

Tags: group-theory, recreational-mathematics

The 8-Puzzle is a famous sliding-block puzzle (a $3\times 3$ grid with one open space) that many readers will have grown up with. Here's an online implementation: https://murhafsousli.github.io/8puzzle

> I am interested in representing the set $ S $ of solvable configurations of the puzzle, especially counting the number of elements of $ S $.

For some time, I was sidetracked by the red herring of thinking that $ S $ is a group.  I recently cured myself of that assumption, since there is no clear way to multiply elements of $ S $.  However, we can consider the group $ H $ of of moves (here we take a "move" to be any sequence of transpositions of a piece into the adjacent empty slot) which, when they act on the solved puzzle $ s_0 \in S $, leave the empty slot in-place.  This is clearly a group since such moves can indeed be composed.  Clearly $ H $ is a subgroup of $ S_8 $ since it acts by permuting 8 elements (the 8 tiles).

> I would conjecture that $ H $ is $ A_8 $, but I am having some trouble proving it.  Is there a simple argument?

If I were to prove this conjecture (and assuming it's true regardless of where we take the empty slot to be fixed), it would imply that $ |S| = 9 \times |A_8| = 9! / 2 $.

Comment: I grew up with the $15$-puzzle

Comment: Every possible (available, solvable) configuration of 9 pieces (including the empty space) is a permutation of the 'solved'  position. And permutations can be composed, making another permutation. Additionally, if you compose two solvable permutations the result is solvable, too. So, yes, they form a group.

Comment: @CiaPan That's definitely not right.  If you take two pieces (not empty) on the solved puzzle and transpose them, the resulting configuration is unsolvable.  And even if it were true that all permutations were solvable, you did not propose a way to compose two moves.  You will find, if you sit down to write a formula, that there's no clear way to do it.

Comment: @JakeMirra I talk about _solvable_ (available) permutations. Swapping two adjacent tiles is not a valid move in the puzzle, so it doesn't constitute a _solvable_ permutation, so it's out of context.

Comment: Youve repeated the same false claim twice now. 
 Consider $ \sigma = (9,8) $ and $ \tau = (9,6) $.  They are both legal permutations, but $ \tau \circ \sigma \circ \tau = (6,8) $.

Comment: @JakeMirra - if you read CiaPan's first comment carefully, they are making 2 separate stmts: Permutations form a group (obvious), and Solvable positions also form a group (less obvious but still true).  CiaPan never said these two groups are the same group.